# Why are some Python standard libraries written in .so while most others are in .py?

Tags: python, standard-library, .so

Most of the standard libraries are written in Python .py files, but some are in .so files on Unix and .pyd on Windows. For example os is written in os.py while pyexpat is written in pyexpat.cpython-36m-darwin.so. What's so special about these .so libraries?

Comment: going by the tag wiki, `.so` files are c++

Comment: This is probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608465/what-is-inside-so-file-of-python-library-distribution

Comment: @mast3rd3mon not neccessarily C++ files are *.so. Even C files also can be *.so. To be more clear *.so lib can generated using C and C++ files. Where as many modules in Python example Numpy is written in C and imported to Python.

Comment: @danglingpointer thats my bad, i meant `are written in c++`, i somehow forgot to type that

Comment: @mast3rd3mon in the case of python, those are mostly `written in C`

Answer (score 5):

`.so` files are shared object files, which are compiled shared libraries. They are usually written in a compiled language like `C`, `C++`, `Go` etc.

Python being an interpreted language, code written in it tends to be slow, because the interpreter needs to go through each line of the code being executed, translate it into some sort of intermediate byte code and then finally execute the byte code. This can be slow.

In cases where performance is a concern, modules are written in a lower level language like `C` which is then compiled to a shared object file. These files can be loaded by the Python interpreter and used like a normal python module. Because these modules are already compiled to machine code, they can be directly executed without going through the interpreter, and thus they are much faster than the equivalent code written in Python.

Writing in a lower level language like `C` also allows for efficient usage of the memory and even release the global interpreter lock in order to exploit multicore parellilism. Scientific modules like `numpy`, `scipy` are examples of these.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't numpy written in Python? I see it's all .py files in my installation directory.

Comment: Some part of it is in Python but the core part is in C (if you see here you will see the C source: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/core/src). It also depends on a linear algebra library like BLAS for matrix functions. These libraries are usually implemented in Fortran and also loaded via the .so mechanism.

Comment: @multigoodverse numpy is not written in Python is mostly written in C. *.so is the shared object library created in C and that is imported into Python.