# How can I import a pyd file in spyder from anaconda?

Tags: python, spyder, ddl, anaconda3, pyd

I'm using spyder from Anaconda. I'm trying to import a pyd file but this message appeared: 'DLL load failed while importing _py_bbt_driver: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.'. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks.

I tried to use pip install in the anaconda prompt but it didn't work and I also tried to use the sys library but it didn't work neither.

Comment: That could be quite similar to this other [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46609322/8547331), where the .pyd was built for a different Python version. A look into [DependencyWalker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) or [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) for this pyd will tell you more - look out for the `Python3x.dll` listed on the left side panel and compare that with the one of Spyder (see menu) or it's qtconsole (see terminal banner).

Comment: Please edit in one more info: is `import _py_bbt_driver` what you're trying to do? Or is that the name of another DLL, which may be a dependency of your import? Because in the latter case, ignore my comment above.

Comment: _py_bbt_driver is the pyd file.